# Return the classification automatically using DOB and range of numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

For the following table below I would like to input the classification(I4-I10) on (G2)   automatically based on the date of birth of the user(C2) and the number of reps that they did F2 compared to the range of repetitions for the appropriate age group.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to change the scheme with only the lower value, like:

[image]

In that case case it's only a sequence of **Loopup/Match**...
The formula can be:

```
=INDEX(I4:I10;MATCH(F2;OFFSET(I4:I10;0;MATCH(ROUND((TODAY()-C2)/365;0);J3:O3;1));1))
```

Splitted you have:

```
=MATCH(ROUND((TODAY()-C2)/365;0);J3:O3;1)     -> [P3] To find the age and than the Index of the column to use
=MATCH(F2;OFFSET(I4:I10;0;P3);1)      -> [Q4] To find the Index in the column of P3.
=INDEX(I4:I10;Q4)      -> Recover the text.
```